# Partial derivative of this function

Tags: calculus

If $u=\log(x^3+y^3+z^3-3xyz)$ then prove that $\dfrac{\partial u}{\partial x}+\dfrac{\partial u}{\partial y}+\dfrac{\partial u}{\partial z}=\dfrac{3}{x+y+z} $.

I got:
$$\frac{\partial u}{\partial x}=\frac{3x^2-3yz}{x^3+y^3+z^3-3xyz}$$

$$\dfrac{\partial u}{\partial y}=\frac{3y^2-3xz}{x^3+y^3+z^3-3xyz}$$

$$\dfrac{\partial u}{\partial z}=\frac{3z^2-3xy}{x^3+y^3+z^3-3xyz}$$

Adding all of these derivatives I get something like:

$$\frac{\partial u}{\partial x}+\frac{\partial u}{\partial y}+\frac{\partial u}{\partial z}=\frac{3x^2+3y^2+3z^2-3xy-3yz-3zx}{x^3+y^3+z^3-3xyz}$$

I don't know how to simplify this further.....how do I proceed from here?

Comment: You could extract the factor of $3$.

Comment: I have done that but I get stuck after that

Comment: What do you get if you multiply the numerator by $x+y+z$?

Comment: It's coming to be something big  . It's not factorising

Comment: It's probably because your numerator in the last step is wrong, check again.

Comment: Ah it's coming.. Thanks a lot! This was such a silly mistake

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Since the denominator can't be changed, you should factor it first.

\begin{align} 
x^3+y^3+z^3-3xyz &= x^3+y^3+3x^2y+3xy^2+z^3-3xyz-3x^2y-3xy^2 \\
&=(x+y)^3+z^3-3xy(x+y+z) \\
&=(x+y+z)((x+y)^2+z^2-(x+y)z)-3xy(x+y+z) \\
&=(x+y+z)(x^2+2xy+y^2+z^2-xy-xz-3xy) \\
&=(x+y+z)(x^2+y^2+z^2-xy-yz-zx) \end{align}

For the numerator I think it's easy to find the factor.